# Is there a way to create a scrollViewISZooming method similar to the scrollViewDidEndZooming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am looking for a way to create a scrollViewIsZooming method that is called while zooming is occuring. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I am wanting to use it to keep the content centered in the scrollView while zooming. If I use the scrollViewDidEndZooming method, the content snaps back to the center after zooming is finished.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a zooming propriety on UIScrollView :

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isZooming) BOOL zooming
```

If you check it in each

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

call it should work.

Answer (score 0):

What about viewForZoomingInScrollView:

Answer (score 0):

If you put a pinch gesture recogniser in the view then connect it to an action you can control zooming that way. I have an action "doPinch" and an outlet "pinchRecognizer" that I use like this:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
return self.zoomableImage;
}
```

Then

```
- (IBAction)doPinch:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"In the pinch action now with scale: %f", self.pinchRecognizer.scale);
[scrollView setZoomScale:self.pinchRecognizer.scale animated:NO];
}
```

Might be easier. Note that scrollView is my outlet connected to the scroll view.